# AWS CLI put-lifecycle-configuration between buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a bucket that I manually created an object lifecycle policy for; now I'd like to apply that policy to other buckets.  I run the following command to get the existing policy:

`aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket mybucket > s3_lifecyclepolicy.json`

Which generates this file:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 7
            },
            "ID": "7 Day Expire",
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NoncurrentDays": 14
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I then try to run apply the policy like so:

`aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket anotherbucket --lifecycle-configuration file://s3_lifecyclepolicy.json`

But get this error:

```
A client error (MalformedXML) occurred when calling the 
PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration
operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not 
validate against
our published schema
```

I've tried modifying the json, and the cli will error out with a syntax error, so the json should be correct, but I'm not sure where the XML related error is coming from.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `Prefix` is a required parameter, even though it did not display in the `get-bucket-lifecycle` output.

This version works:

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 7
      },
      "ID": "7 Day Expire",
      "Prefix": "",
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
        "NoncurrentDays": 14
      }
    }
  ]
}
```